# KeyValuePair binding to a wpf control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have:

```
public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> SearchInAllFiles { get; private set; }
```

This is what I tried:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SearchInAllFiles}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="{Binding}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I need the `Key` as the image url and the `Value` as the image-text of `SearchInAllFiles`. What needs to be be adjusted for my XAML ?

Comment: If Key is the image URL you should obviously write `<Image Source="{Binding Key}" />`

Comment: @Clemens this is how the data looks like, at run time: https://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/DyDF . By the way I dont see any result in the GUI

Comment: Don't post screenshots. Edit your question instead, with all relevant details. Have you set the DataContext of your MainWindow to an instance of the class with the SearchInAllFiles property?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show image then binding should be like below.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SearchInAllFiles}">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="{Binding Key}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```